# Linkage error when I try to run my Java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I have a JDK-17 Eclipse project.

I compile it using Eclipse and try to run using Eclipse. When I try to run:

> Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class XXX.blockchainUI.MainWindow
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: XXX/blockchainUI/MainWindow has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0

I have `java` symlinked to JDK-17 `java`:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Mar 27 15:51 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Mar 27 15:51 /etc/alternatives/java.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Mar 27 15:56 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Mar 27 15:56 /etc/alternatives/javac.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javac.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Mar 27 15:57 /etc/alternatives/javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Mar 27 15:57 /etc/alternatives/javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jan 20 11:12 /etc/alternatives/javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jan 20 11:12 /etc/alternatives/javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javah.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Mar 27 15:58 /etc/alternatives/javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Mar 27 15:58 /etc/alternatives/javap.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javap.1.gz
```

Note that to be sure I cleaned all files under `bin/` directory, this does not help.

Comment: Class file version 63 is Java 19, change the project Java compliance settings in Eclipse to be Java 17.

Comment: @greg-449 How to change the project Java compliance settings in Eclipse to be Java 17?

Comment: Project Properties > Java Compiler